# Python boxes flickering on the screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, shapes

I'm using OpenCV to detect objects from a video

I have the following questions:

1. How can I pause the screen after an object is detected (for better performance).
2. How can I make each rectangle flicker at a different frequency (specified in Hz). I would like to achieve a similar result to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bpBvbPYK5Ec (minute 2:00)
3. Over the object the same shape should be drawn and flicker using given frequency

Please be mindful that I am new to Python.

Here is the code I have so far:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load Yolo
net = cv2.dnn.readNet("yolov3.weights", "yolov3.cfg")
classes = []
with open("coco.names", "r") as f:
  classes = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
output_layers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
colors = (0, 255, 255)

# Use webcam
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
  _, img = camera.read()
  height, width, channels = img.shape

  # Detecting objects
  blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 0.00392, (320, 320), (0, 0, 0), True, crop=False)
  net.setInput(blob)
  outs = net.forward(output_layers)

  # Show screen information
  class_ids = []
  confidences = []
  boxes = []
  for out in outs:
    for detection in out:
      scores = detection[5:]
      class_id = np.argmax(scores)
      confidence = scores[class_id]
      if confidence > 0.5:
        # Object is detected
           center_x = int(detection[0] * width)
           center_y = int(detection[1] * height)
           w = int(detection[2] * width)
           h = int(detection[3] * height)
           # Rectangle coordinates
           x = int(center_x - w / 2)
           y = int(center_y - h / 2)
           boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
           confidences.append(float(confidence))
           class_ids.append(class_id)
    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.5, 0.4)

    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
    for i in range(len(boxes)):
       if class_ids[i] != 0:
        if i in indexes: 
              x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
              label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
              color = colors
              cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
              cv2.putText(img, label, (x, y + 30), font, 3, color, 3)
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use time module -  time.sleep(number of s). I don't know if this will help You, but You can try